# Generated SQL from Linq GroupJoin is ignoring all conditions

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I'm trying to query the number of tickets open per hour in a single day using LINQ to SQL query syntax. I'm getting the right results however the generated SQL is very different from what I would expect.

My query on LinqPad Is:

```
int[] hours = Enumerable.Range(0, 24).ToArray();
DateTime Nov = new DateTime(2023, 11, 14);
var q = (
            from h in hours
            join t in Tickets on h equals t.CreatedAt.Hour into ht
            from lht in ht.Where(tk => (tk.CreatedAt.Date == Nov.Date) && (tk.OrganizationId == 1) && (!tk.IsDeleted) ).DefaultIfEmpty()
            group lht by h into ftable
            select new {id = ftable.Key, count  = ftable.Count(f => f != null)}
        ).Dump();
```

and for some reason, the generated SQL query is a simple selection of the entire tickets table:

```
SELECT `t`.`Id`, `t`.`ClosedAt`, `t`.`CreatedAt`, `t`.`CreatedBy`, `t`.`isDeleted`, `t`.`LastUpdatedAt`, `t`.`LastUpdatedBy`, `t`.`LinkedSessionId`, `t`.`OrganizationId`, `t`.`Priority`, `t`.`PropertyId`, `t`.`PublicId`, `t`.`RecipientId`, `t`.`Source`, `t`.`Status`, `t`.`Subject`, `t`.`TicketId`
FROM `tickets` AS `t`
```

I'm not sure what is happening here but it looks like the line `join t in Tickets on h equals t.CreatedAt.Hour into ht` is simply fetching the whole table and then doing the rest of the grouping and where conditions in memory, which is hugely inefficient.

Has anyone encountered something like this before or can explain this behavior, and how can I force it to generate a normal LEFT JOIN with WHERE and GROUP BY clauses in the generated sql.

Comment: SInce your query starts with an in-memory collection `hours`, I expect that most or all of the  LINQ query is being processed as an `IEnumerable<>` and not an `IQueryable<>`. All of the join operations are being done in memory, with full table scans and retrievals in the database.  A significant rewrite of the query is going to be needed to make it efficient.  ...

Comment: ...  I would start by: (1) Drop the hours logic at the top and move it to something like `group x by x.CreatedAt.Hour into ...` after data has been retrieved and filtered. No array is needed. (2) Start your query by retrieving and filtering `Tickets` using a date/time range. Something like `from t in Tickets.Where(t => t.CreatedAt >= Nov && t.CreatedAt < Nov.AddDays(1))`.  SQL can efficiently iuse an index to retrieve a date range like that. (If you do not have an index oin `Tickets(CreatedAt)` you should create one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start query from local collection, it means you will use `Enumerable` extensions which means loading whole tables into memory and no filters will be applied.
I would suggest to group existing data on the server and later enrich data with missed hours:

```cs
DateTime Nov = new DateTime(2023, 11, 14);
var startDate = Nov;
var endDate = startDate.AddDays(1);

var query =
    from t in Tickets
    where t.CreatedAt >= startDate && t.CreatedAt < endDate
    group t by t.CreatedAt.Hour into g
    select new 
    {
        id = g.Key, 
        count = g.Count()
    };

int[] hours = Enumerable.Range(0, 24).ToArray();

var enriched = 
    from h in hours
    join d in query on h equals d.id into gj
    from d in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        id = h,
        count = d == null ? 0 : d.count
    };

enriched.Dump();
```

Comment: Question (because I do not know the answer offhand): In the second LINQ query above, since you are joining an IEnumerable (hours) to a IQueryable (query), will the query part only execute once, or will it execute once per hours-iteration? If the latter, a .ToList() might be needed.

Comment: `query` will be asked for `Enumerator` and executed once. It is just parameter for  GroupJoin - `hours.GroupJoin(query, ...)`

Comment: Thanks SvyatoslavDanyliv and @T-N, spent a couple of hours debugging this